# I want to handle message when notification received with app not running

Tags: android, notifications, push

In Android APP, I have already use FCM to receive Cloud Message, when the app is foreground , the `MyFirebaseMessageService.java` (I defined) runned. However when the app is background or not running ,The `MyFirebaseMessageService.java` doesn't run, I can also receive notification, when I click the notification, Where can I get the cloud message?

Answer (score 0):

Send your push as data and not as notification, and it will be received always in MyFirebaseMessageService onMessageReceived.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: But if I do not have a server, how can I send data ?

Comment: How do you sending notifications now?

Comment: Using the Firebase console

Comment: Check the intent of your main activity, it should contain the data that you added to notification, and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much,I have got the data.However, three is a new problem.if there are two message ,when I click first Notification,the activity created, and I get data,then I click another ,I can't get the data.